# Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have x dimension(s). but got array with shape y,z

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm very new to Tensorflowjs and Tensorflow in general. I have some data, which is capacity used out of 100%, so a number between 0 and 100, and there are 5 hours per day these capacities are noted. So I have a matrix of 5 days, containing 5 percentages out of 100%.

I have the following model:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [5, 5] }));
model.compile({ loss: 'binaryCrossentropy', optimizer: 'sgd' });

// Input data
// Array of days, and their capacity used out of 
// 100% for 5 hour period
const xs = tf.tensor([
  [11, 23, 34, 45, 96],
  [12, 23, 43, 56, 23],
  [12, 23, 56, 67, 56],
  [13, 34, 56, 45, 67],
  [12, 23, 54, 56, 78]
]);

// Labels
const ys = tf.tensor([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]]);

// Train the model using the data.
model.fit(xs, ys).then(() => {
  model.predict(tf.tensor(5)).print();
}).catch((e) => {
  console.log(e.message);
});
```

I'm getting an error returned: `Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 5,5`. So I suspect I'm entering or mapping my data incorrectly in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error comes **from a mismatch of the size** of the training and test data from one hand on the other hand by what is defined as the input of your model

```
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [5, 5] }));
```

The [inputShape](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.12.0/#layers.dense) is your input dimension. Here it is 5, because each features is an array of size 5.

```
model.predict(tf.tensor(5))
```

Also to test your model, your data should have the same shape as when your are training your model. Your model cannot predict anything with `tf.tensor(5)`. Because your training data and your test data size do not match. Consider this test data instead `tf.tensor2d([5, 1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 5])`

Here is a working [snipet](https://codepen.io/edkeveked/pen/djXvoz?editors=1011)