# Build neural network in TensorflowJS

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I build a chatbot with nodejs and TensorflowJS.

My code is based on [This tutorial](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/contextual-chat-bots-with-tensorflow-4391749d0077)

I'm having troubleto 'translate' the neural network build.

From :

```
# Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(train_x[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(train_y[0]), activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net)

# Define model and setup tensorboard
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_dir='tflearn_logs')
# Start training (apply gradient descent algorithm)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
model.save('model.tflearn')
```

And I got so far this:

```
  // Build neural network:
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: training.length, activation: 'relu', inputShape: [train_x[0].length]}));
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: train_y[0].length, activation: 'linear'}));
  model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});
```

The point is I can't 'predict' with my JS code.

[I got this erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkTB7.png)

[And this is my xs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWXrG.png)

Full code https://github.com/ran-j/ChatBotNodeJS/blob/master/routes/index.js#L184

Is diferente that [Expected dense_Dense1_input to have shape "a" but got array with shape "b"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790230/expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-shape-a-but-got-array-with-shape-b) ,becouse its a this is a 'traduction' from python and not erro from using create neural network

```
train_x[0].length = 48
train_y[0].length = 9
```

I got erro when I predit my model.

Comment: Can you please copy paste the error instead of the image ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expected dense\_Dense1\_input to have shape "a" but got array with shape "b"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790230/expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-shape-a-but-got-array-with-shape-b)

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error when checking : expected dense_Dense1_input to have 2 dimension(s), but got array with shape [48]

Comment: not the same, that error was slove

Comment: Both errors are similar. You need to follow the same steps as the one outlined in the previous answer. To solve the error you have now, whether you change the shape of your model or the shape of your training data which is the same thing as what you have to do with the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: 8,
    inputShape: [null, train_x[0].length]
}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: 8
}));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: train_y[0].length
    activation: 'softmax'
}));

model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: 'sgd'});

await model.fit(x_tensor, y_tensor, {
    epochs: 1000,
    batchSize: 8
})
```