# Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense2 to have shape x, but got array with shape y

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

It is my first steps in the tensorflow.

**Idea**

There is some pattern of numbers (the array of numbers: `Pattern = number[]`). And the category that corresponds to this pattern (the number from 0 to 2: `Category = 0 | 1 | 2`). I have follow the structure data: `xs =  Pattern[]`, `ys = Category[]`.

For example:

```
xs = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], ..., [9, 10, 11, 12]];
ys = [1, 0, ..., 2];
```

I want the neural network to find a match between `xs[0]` and `xy[0]`, and so on. I want to pass the neural network data like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` and get a result close to `1`.

```
model.predict(tf.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4])) // ≈1
```

**My code**

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const xs = tf.tensor2d([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
]);
const ys = tf.tensor1d([0, 1, 2]);

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, inputShape: xs.shape, activation: 'relu' }));
                                   ^ - Pattern length, it is constant
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 3, activation: 'softmax' }));
model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });

model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 500 });
```

I get follow error:

> Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have 3 dimension(s). but got array with shape 3,4

I don't understand how to explain my data structure for the neural network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right solution for my task.
Just need to use the `dataset`

https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#tf.Sequential.fitDataset

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const xArray = [
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
];

const yArray = [0, 1, 2];
const { length } = yArray;

const xs = tf.data.array(xArray);
const ys = tf.data.array(yArray);

const xyDataset = tf.data.zip({ xs: xDataset, ys: yDataset }).batch(length).shuffle(length);

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: length, inputShape: [length], activation: 'relu' }));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 3, activation: 'softmax' }));
model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });

model.fitDataset(xyDataset, { epochs: 500 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The model inputShape is `[3,4]` . To fit or predict with this model, it needs a data with the form `[b, 3, 4]` where b is the batch shape. The batch shape is missing when trying to fit your model with `xs`.

The model inputShape should rather be [4] so that xs can be used for prediction. Instead of using `xs.shape`, it could be `xs.shape.slice(-1)`.

```
const xs = tf.tensor2d([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
]);
const ys = tf.tensor1d([0, 1, 2]);

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, inputShape: xs.shape.slice(1), activation: 'relu' }));
                                  
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 3, activation: 'softmax' }));
model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });

model.fit(xs, ys);
model.predict(xs).print()
```

---

Besides, if the goal of the model is to predict a category as indicated by the use of `softmax` and `categoricalCrossentropy`, then, the label should be one-hot encoded.

Similar answers:

- [expected dense dense1 input to have shape a but got array with shape b](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790230/expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-shape-a-but-got-array-with-shape-b)
- [Error when checking input: expected dense_Dense1_input to have x dimension(s). but got array with shape y,z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326770/error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-x-dimensions-b/51388792#51388792)

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. Yes it fixes the error, but after happens new error "Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense2 to have shape [,3], but got array with shape [3,1]". I understand to need prepare the data or to need change inputShape, but I dont understand how to do.

Comment: I run your code with the change and it worked if you only change: `inputShape: xs.shape.slice(1)`

Comment: Hm... this is strange. My code now:

`import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');

const xs = tf.tensor2d([
  [1, 2, 3, 4],
  [5, 6, 7, 8],
  [9, 10, 11, 12],
]);
const ys = tf.tensor1d([0, 1, 2]);

const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 4, inputShape: xs.shape.slice(-1), activation: 'relu' }));
model.add(tf.layers.dense({ units: 3, activation: 'softmax' }));
model.compile({ optimizer: 'adam', loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', metrics: ['accuracy'] });

model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 500 });`

Comment: And I get follow error: `Error when checking target: expected dense_Dense2 to have shape [,3], but got array with shape [3,1]`
The error on the second layer

Comment: I am able to make a prediction out of it. Are you using the latest version of tfjs ?

Comment: I using follow version: 
@tensorflow/tfjs ^2.4.0
@tensorflow/tfjs-node ^2.4.0

Comment: I am very grateful for your help!

Comment: I dont understand that was changed, but now it is working!