# Learning XOR using Tensorflow.js

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Hello I am creating my first neural network using Tensorflow.js.

I want to use the points (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1) and the labels 0, 1, 1, 0 as inputs to my NN. I tried it the following way:

```
async function runModel() {

  // Build and compile model.
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 2, inputShape: [2]}));
  model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

  // Generate some synthetic data for training.
  const xs = tf.tensor2d([[1], [0]], [2,1]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([[1]], [1, 1]);

  // Train model with fit().
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 10});

  // Run inference with predict().
  model.predict(tf.tensor2d([[0], [1]], [2, 1])).print();
}

runModel()
```

I end up with the error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error when checking input: expected
> dense_Dense1_input to have shape [,2], but got array with shape [2,1].

and I tried to play with all the parameters but I don't get it (even with documentation) how to succeed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error when checking input: expected dense\_Dense1\_input to have x dimension(s). but got array with shape y,z](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326770/error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-x-dimensions-b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51326770/error-when-checking-input-expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-x-dimensions-b/51388792#51388792) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51790230/expected-dense-dense1-input-to-have-shape-a-but-got-array-with-shape-b), this error is thrown when there is a mismatch of the shape expected by the model and the shape of the training data.

> expected dense_Dense1_input to have shape [,2], but got array with shape [2,1]

The error thrown is meaningful enough to help solve the issue. The first layer is expecting a tensor of shape `[,2]` since the inputShape is  `[2]`. But `xs` has the shape `[2, 1]`, it should rather have the shape `[1, 2]`.

In the model, the last layer will return 2 values whereas in reality it should be only one ( an xor operation outputs only a single value). Therefore instead of `units: 2`, it should be `units: 1`. That means that `ys` should have the shape `[,1]`. The shape of `ys` is already what the model is supposed to have - so no changes there.

The shape of the tensor used for prediction should match the model input shape ie `[, 2]`

By making the above changes, it becomes the following:

```
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [2]}));
  model.compile({optimizer: 'sgd', loss: 'meanSquaredError'});

  // Generate some synthetic data for training.
  const xs = tf.tensor2d([[1, 0]]);
  const ys = tf.tensor2d([[1]], [1, 1]);

  // Train model with fit().
  await model.fit(xs, ys, {epochs: 10});

  // Run inference with predict().
  model.predict(tf.tensor([[0, 1]], [1, 2])).print()
```